# Accessing private fields, when explicit 'this' parameter is provided

Tags: typescript

Not sure, is it a bug or feature, but if i provide an explicit 'this' parameter
to a function, i will not get access to private properties throw this.

```
class Test {
    private _document: any;    
}

const myDynamicProp = '....';


Object.defineProperty(Test.prototype, myDynamicProp , {
      get: function(this: Test) {
        return this._document[myDynamicProp];  // no access to private  and protected field      
      }
  });
```

Can anyone suggest some docs where this moment is clarified ?

Comment: What TypeScript version? In Playground (at asking time TypeScript 2.4) it is inaccessible. http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html

Answer (score 0):

> will not get access to private properties throw this

Only methods / functions explicitly in the class body will get access to private fields. Allowing external extensions to get it from `this` would be similar to allowing external classes to get it from instances and is hence not allowed.

## More

Your should use a getter instead of `defineProperty` :

```
class Test {
    private _document: any;    
    get foo() { return this._document }
}
```